# Laravel Eloquent, How to access eloquent on 3 tables with where?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 3 tables like this below :

```
Items table
id | name
1  | Laptop
2  | Computer
3  | Tv

Production table
id | date
1  | 2021-10-01
2  | 2021-10-03
3  | 2021-10-30

Detail table
id | production_id| item_id |qty
1  | 1            | 1       | 5 
2  | 1            | 3       | 10
 
3  | 2            | 1       |2
4  | 2            | 2       |3
5  | 2            | 3       |23
```

And  what I'm trying to achieve is like this :

```
(where Production dateBetween this date and that date)
Items       |Sum qty 
Laptop      | 7
Computer    | 3
Tv          | 33
```

How to do this in eloquent way ?

Should I use hasManyThrough relationship ?

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is concatenation problem, i would not use standard relationships for this. Instead let `mysql` solve this, by creating a custom query in the `ORM`.

The strategy is to join all the rows, group it by the name of the product. Sum the quantity and create the where condition for the dates.

```
$items = Item::select('name', DB::raw('SUM(details.qty) as quantity'))
    ->join('details', 'items.id', '=', 'details.item_id')
    ->join('productions', 'productions.id', '=', 'details.production_id')
    ->whereBetween('productions.date', [now()->subMonth(), now())
    ->groupBy('details.name')
    ->get();
```

You could loop the data like so.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item->name;
    $item->quantity;
}
```

Comment: Have not tested the code, as it is fairly substantial problem you have, if you run into a problem please write a comment :)

Comment: Thank you, I have tested the code and it works, but you forgot to add the get() in the end :)

Comment: Glad it worked, yh the get() was forgotten thats the price of writing pseudo code on stackoverflow :)